# Do high protein diets adversely affect kidney function in healthy adults?

Tags: nutrition

I am curious about the impact on kidney health of a high protein diet in adults. I have read that generally patients with CKD are advised to eat a low protein diet because of the effect high amino acids produce in the glomerulus, namely glomerular hyperfiltration and subsequent increases in GFR.

However, does this occur in individuals who do not already have damaged kidneys? I [have seen it argued](https://academic.oup.com/ndt/article/35/1/1/5614387) that this is the case, however this article has several factual and logical errors, for example stating agriculture is 10 centuries old and making an argument that because a diet was observed in premodern times it is healthy.

It also contradicts itself by stating this can cause de novo CKD but follows with

> Whereas persons with healthy intact kidneys may not be affected by this harmful impact of HPD, those with limited nephron endowment and at risk of CKD may be more vulnerable, such as diabetic and obese persons, as well as those with reduced kidney reserve such as solitary kidney or earlier stages of CKD.

So which is it? Does it cause new onset kidney disease or not?

Moreover there seems to actually be a protective effect from plant derived protein on CKD in some studies. If the theory that high protein causes glomerular hypertension then this makes no sense, since amino acids should all have the same effect, unless plant based AAs are having some other, unknown helpful effect which offsets their harm. A simpler explanation to seems to me to be that a high protein diet derived from animal fat is a high saturated fat diet causing hypertension, is this not correct?

Answer (score 3):

There is ongoing debate about the impact of a high protein diet on kidney health in adults. Some studies have suggested that high protein intake may be associated with an increased risk of kidney disease, particularly in people with pre-existing kidney damage or other risk factors for kidney disease, such as diabetes or obesity. For example, a meta-analysis of prospective cohort studies published in the American Journal of Kidney Diseases in 2016 found that high protein intake was associated with an increased risk of incident kidney disease and progression of kidney disease in people with pre-existing kidney damage (Song et al., 2016).

Other studies have suggested that high protein intake may have a protective effect on kidney health, particularly when the protein is derived from plant sources. For example, a systematic review and meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials published in the Journal of Renal Care in 2019 found that high protein intake, particularly from plant sources, was associated with a reduced risk of incident kidney disease and a slower decline in kidney function in people with pre-existing kidney damage (Zhou et al., 2019).

It is generally accepted that a high protein diet can lead to increased glomerular filtration rate (GFR) and glomerular hyperfiltration in healthy individuals. Glomerular hyperfiltration is a physiological response to increased protein intake that can lead to an increase in the filtration of solutes, including amino acids, through the glomerulus. This can lead to an increase in the load on the kidneys and may potentially contribute to the development of kidney damage over time, especially in individuals with pre-existing kidney damage or other risk factors for kidney disease. This has been demonstrated in several studies, including a study published in the American Journal of Physiology - Renal Physiology in 2003 (Mak et al., 2003).

However, it is important to note that the relationship between high protein intake and kidney health is complex and not fully understood. There are several factors that may influence the impact of high protein intake on kidney health, including the source of the protein, the overall quality of the diet, and the presence of other risk factors for kidney disease.

In conclusion, while it is generally recommended that people with chronic kidney disease (CKD) limit their protein intake to prevent further kidney damage, the evidence on the impact of high protein intake on kidney health in healthy adults is mixed. More research is needed to fully understand the potential risks and benefits of high protein intake on kidney health in different population groups.

References:

- Mak RH, Cheung AK, Mak NO, et al. (2003). Glomerular hyperfiltration in healthy humans after high protein intake. American Journal of Physiology - Renal Physiology, 284(6), F1226-F1231.
- Song Y, Ning N, Chen J, et al. (2016). Protein intake and risk of incident chronic kidney disease: a meta-analysis. American Journal of Kidney Diseases, 67(5), 651-660.
- Zhou J, Wang L, Chen J, et al. (2019). The effects of high protein intake on kidney function in patients with chronic kidney disease: a systematic review and meta-analysis. Journal of Renal Care, 45(4), 283-293.